# Add rating pop up in iOS application in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, app-store, rating

I want to add rating pop Up inside app.

**Requirements**

1. When user open app three times then app should show rating pop up inside application.
2. That pop up should not be lead to the play store/ app store but the rating must be inside the application. (It must let the user to rate the app without opening the appstore/ playstore).

How can I implement this?

Comment: Have you seen this package? https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_review

Comment: will this package let me rate my app without closing the app in appstore??

Comment: I don't want user to open app store for reviews but it should let the user to rate with in app

Comment: It shows the pop-up within the app - the same pop-up which you would see in a natively built iOS app

Comment: rate_my_app 1.1.1  does this package do the same task?

Comment: At a glance, yes it looks like it would